# How to translate Extensibility mechanisms

Tags: traducción

I have a title in english

> SQL extensibility mechanisms

Which would be a good spanish translation?

Cual sería la mejor traducción para ese titulo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Arquitectura extensible SQL**, creo que es el término técnico que se debe utilizar.

Comment: La palabra "mecanismos" es omitida?

Comment: Yo podría arquitectura extensible, qui´zas en algunos casos pueda decirse que tiene mecanismos extensibles. Pero en su definición técnica SQL es un lenguaje de arquitectura extensible. ¿Qué lo hace extensible? pues debieran ser diferentes mecanismos.

Comment: Si, de hecho el titulo en ingles es "SQL Extensibility Mechanisms and UDFs"  había puesto Mecanismos de extensión de Arquitectura y UDFs, asi esta bien definido?

Comment: Mecanismos de extensibilidad y funciones definidas por el usuario en la arquitectura de SQL

Comment: @Ernesto, no comprendo de donde sale la palabra _arquitectura_ :o

Comment: https://www.google.es/search?q=%22arquitectura+sql%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:es-ES:official&client=firefox-a  basicamente en Google en español se referencian 4590 resultados, con comillas. sin comillas hay un poco más llega hasta Aproximadamente 2.910.000 resultados. En inglés la busqueda da "architecture sql" (con comillas) 269 000 resultados, sin comillas un poco más, 68 millones 600 mil referencias. https://www.google.es/search?q=architecture+sql&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:es-ES:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: De cualquier modo creo, y asi lo dije, que la respuesta correcta debiera ser la de mariocase84  :o;

Answer (score 5):

Considero que la mejor traducción sería:

> Mecanismos de extensibilidad de SQL

De acuerdo con la RAE extensibilidad es:

> extensibilidad.
>
> 1. f. Cualidad de extensible.

Comment: @cMinor Considero que entonces la respuesta de mariocase84 es la mejor opción para traducir la frase que querías